# Are dependencies included from a pom direct o transitive?

Tags: maven

Consider a project my-prject with a pom having a dependency section like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>some.artifact.id</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

where some.artifact.id has:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>something</groupId>
        <artifactId>lib1</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>something</groupId>
        <artifactId>lib2</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My questions:

1 Does Maven see lib1 and lib2 as direct or transitive dependencies of my-project?

2 What happens at compiler time when:

2.1 my-project references a symbol inside lib1

or

2.2 my-project references a symbol inside lib2 ?

Comment: I add some context to my question. I have a situation like the one presented in the question. The project compile if lib1 and lib2 have compile scope. The dependencies are not recognized when scope is provided. I don't understand why.

Comment: Why is the dependency given with `<type>pom</type>`? The given `<scope>compile></scope>` as well the `<type>jar</type>` can be removed.

Comment: I need to import lot of libs in many projects so I put them in a pom.

Comment: If you like to do that create a so called BOM which contains only a dependencyManagement which contains the groupId/artifactId/version of your lib components ... and in your real project you can do a so called BOM import https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#bill-of-materials-bom-poms

Answer (score 1):

You can have a POM with common dependencies and add it as a dependency in your project. Note that you should only do that if you really need the dependencies being present. If you just want to make sure that certain versions of libraries are used, go for a BOM.

Using this POM makes the dependencies *transitive dependencies*. This especially means that the Maven rules for scope resolution kick in. One of the rules is: Transitive dependencies with scope `provided` are removed.

Comment: Ok exactly what I supposed. Thanks!